# Como mostrar el valor de una consulta select count() con html ,jpa y thymeleaf

Tags: java, mysql, html5, thymeleaf, spring-data

Estoy haciendo una consulta a la bd con spring data jpa:

```
@Query(
    value = "select count(*) as total from canasta.usuario;",
    nativeQuery = true
)
long total();
```

Esta consulta me devuelve una tabla llamada total con el valor. Lo que quiero, es poder mostrar ese valor en un `text area` o `input text` con `thymeleaf`.

[image: Resultado esperado]

aqui esta el resultado de la consulta ⬆️⬆️⬆️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude resolver lo hice de esta manera

```
<input style="text-align: center;" type="text" th:value="${total}" readonly>
```

el controlador agregué

```
 service.total();
    model.addAttribute("total", service.total());
```

la consulta query es la misma y el metodo Long total() igual

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar el atributo 'th:value' para unir el resultado al elemento.

Por ejemplo:

```
<textarea th:value="${total()}"></textarea>
```

'th:value' une el resultado del método total() en el elemento ''. Esto va a causar que el resultado de la consulta se muestre en el area de texto.

Una alternativa también es usar el elemento '' con el atributo 'type' seteado a 'text' para que muestre el resultado de la consulta.

Ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" th:value="${total()}" />
```

Comment: Hola , me lanza un error de las dos formas

Comment: hola! cual error?

Comment: Este error   Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "total()" (template: "listar_u" - line 43, col 50)
 at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
 at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
 at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
 ... 98 more